# Отправка файлов в Angular 5

Tags: spring, httpclient, angular5, formdata, multipartfile

Пишу небольшой проект со связкой Angular 5 на фронте и Spring Boot Rest на бекенде. Понадобилось сделать форму с отправкой файлов на сервер.
Вот есть функция:

```js
sbmt(Images: File[]) {
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/product/test', new FormData().append('test', Image[0], Image[0].name)).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Вот обработчик на сервере:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestParam("test") MultipartFile test) {
    System.out.println(test.getOriginalFilename());
}
```

При попытке загрузить получаю ошибку 500 на клиенте, а на сервере бросается исключение:

```
rg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:196) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at
```

Но как же мне все же отправить файл на сервер? Перерыл весь интернет, включая буржуйский. (Вообще, там большая реактивная форма, но мне хоть бы с этим разобраться, там по аналогии сделаю)
Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```js
 sbmt(Form:FormGroup, Images:File[]){
     let r = new FormData();
     r.append('test', Images[0], Images[0].name);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/product/test', r).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Вот так сработало